# How to force the QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2 method to assign a primary key to the resulting vector layer

Tags: pyqgis, export

I am working in a QGIS plugin, and I have a function for exporting a view from SpatiaLite to a shapefile using QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2.

All works seemingly well, however, it adds a primary key/ identifier named 'rowid' to the resulting shapefile.

Here is my function:

```
    def exportSqliteToShape(self, pathSqlite, sqliteLayer, outName, pathShape, epsg):
        vlayer = QgsVectorLayer(pathSqlite + '|layername=' + sqliteLayer, "ogr", )
        options =  QgsVectorFileWriter.SaveVectorOptions()
        options.ct = QgsCoordinateTransform(vlayer.crs(), QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(epsg), QgsProject.instance())
        options.driverName = "ESRI Shapefile"
        options.layerName = sqliteLayer
        options.fileEncoding = "UTF-8"
        options.onlySelectedFeatures = False
        transform_context = QgsProject.instance().transformContext()
        err, result = QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormatV2(vlayer, pathShape, transform_context, options)
```

How can I to set the method (either the vlayer declaration or the writing part) to take an specific column from my view, which is a de facto primary key (although not declared so)?

I am using  QGIS 3.10, SpatiaLite 4.1.1 (all 32 bits).

Comment: Shapefile doesn't support the concept of a primary key (or numeric nulls, which is why it's an  awful target from databases that do). The feature ID in a shapefile is the row number, which is implicit (and unchangable).

Comment: ok, i got it thank you for your answer, can I still find a way to avoid the additional column rowid? or should i just erase it?

Comment: Dropping the key column will prevent any updates. Consider carefully if this is what you want.

Comment: I just noticed that rowid is a column in my view that is inherited from the table in sqlite that is the base for the view. In my view rowid is no pk, in the table it is. In the shapefile, there is a FID that is type ObjectID. So, I can erase it, although it would be cleaner select only the fields that will be included in the shapefile. Thanks.

Comment: I always recommend selecting the columns that you want explicitly (in the order you want them).